# How do I configure Sinatra to serve 403 (Forbidden) on a specific exception?

Tags: ruby, exception, sinatra, rack

Currently, I have something like this:

```
def valid?(stuff)
  #...
end

get '/somewhere'
  return status 403 unless valid?(something) && valid?(something_else)
  # ...
end
```

(In this specific case, I am checking whether a `param` containing a file name is inside the directory allowed for that parameter, to prevent users from accessing what they shouldn't.)

But it gets unwieldy, especially since I have the same structure in multiple places. I'd rather do something like this:

```
def ensure_valid(stuff)
  raise Forbidden unless valid?(stuff)
end

get '/somewhere'
  ensure_valid(something)
  ensure_valid(something_else)
  # ...
end
```

Is there such an exception? If not, how can I configure Sinatra (or Rack, for that matter) to abort the request with `status 403` if it catches a custom exception?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`halt 403 unless valid?(something) && valid?(something_else)` should also work

source: http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Halting

Comment: Awesome! Can't test now, but reading the docs on it, `halt` looks like exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe what you're looking for is the "error" block?

http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Error

```
error MyCustomError do
    return status 403
end

raise MyCustomError unless valid?(thing)
```

Comment: Yeah, that looks good. Unfortunately, it doesn't work on `development` env unless I `disable :show_exceptions`. Oh well...